# Authentication not works when users are stored in alternative table

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have problems with development of CakePHP2's authentication system, where users are stored in database table `participants` (not `users`, like usual).

It simply does not authenticate participant.

Table `participants` have next structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `participants` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` char(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

File AppController.php have content like this:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('Cookie', 'Session', 'Auth');
    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Participant';
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'name', 'password' => 'password');
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'participants', 'action' => 'login');
        //$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'participants', 'action' => 'logout'); // i will use this later
        //$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'participants', 'action' => 'index');
    }
}
```

File ParticipantsController.php have content like:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

    class ParticipantsController extends AppController {

        function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter(); 
      $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('registration', 'login', 'forgotten', 'recreate', 'confirm');
        }

        function login() {

            if ($this->Auth->login()) {

            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'participants', 'action'=>'view'));

        } else {
            // it always end-up here
            //pr($this->data);
            //pr(AuthComponent::password($this->data['Participant']['password']));
            //exit;

            $this->Session->setFlash( __('Error, please try again.', true) );

        }

    }
```

I don't know what is wrong here, can you please help me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be your configuration of fields and userModel

`$this->Auth->fields`

My working code is closer to :

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Participant'
                   , 'fields' => array('username' => 'name', 'password' => 'password')
                   )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   public function beforeFilter() {
         parent::beforeFilter(); 
         $this->Auth->allow(array('registration', 'login', 
                'forgotten', 'recreate', 'confirm'));
    }
```

Why your functions is not public in controllers?

Comment: nope, still the same - $this->Auth->login() does not authenticate in this case. since application is in debug mode, it looks like no sql query is executed at all, since there is no list of sql queries in bottom page of the layout...