# Cakephp 2.4.5 Authentication functionality not working

Tags: cakephp-2.4

I am new to Cakephp and trying to make a simple user register and login application.        After Writing the code, problem which i am facing is that my login form is authorizing any     Email and password and redirecting to that page that i have been set after login.
Here is my code:

In **AppController.php**

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller 
{
var $components = array('Auth');                                                                      
}
```

In **UserController.php**

```
<?php
//Filename  -UsersController.php

//Registering new users and login
class UsersController extends AppController
{

 public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
 public $components = array('Session',
                        'Auth' => array(
                           'authenticate' => array(
                           'Form' => array (
                           'fields' => array('username'=>'email','password'=>'password')
 ))));

 /**
  *  Function for saving a new user
  */
  public function index()
  {
  if($this->request->is('post'))
  {
  //print_r($this->request->data);die;  
  $this->User->create();
  if($this->User->save($this->request->data))
  {
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Congrats, you are registered successfully'));
  return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index')); 
  } 
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to store the user'));
  } 
  }


  /**
   *  Function for login functionality
   */
   function beforeFilter()
{
 $this->Auth->loginRedirect=array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'welcome');
 $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'welcome');
 }

 public function login()
 {
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
      if($this->Auth->login())
      {
        //print_r($this->request->data);die;
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
      } 
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
 }

 public function logout() {
                        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
                          } }
```

In model **User.php**

```
    <?php 
        // Filename - User.php
        // Model for registering new users
       App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
       App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
       class User extends AppModel
       {        
public $validate = array(
                        'username'=>array('required'=>array(
                        'rule'=>array('notEmpty'),                                                  
                        'message'=>'Username is required'
                                                           )),
                        'password'=>array('required'=>array(
                         'rule'=>array('notEmpty'),                                   
                         'message'=>'Password is required'
                                                           )),
                        'email'=>array('required'=>array(
                        'rule'=>array('notEmpty'),                                   
                        'message'=>'Email is required'
                                                        ))  
                        );
     public function beforeSave($options = array())
 {
     if(isset($this->data['User']['password']))
{
$passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
$this->data['User']['password']=
    $passwordHasher->hash($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
        }
       }
```

In **login.ctp**

```
   <?php
         echo $this->Form->create();
         echo $this->Form->input('username',array('style'=>'width:200px;'));
         echo $this->Form->input('password',array('style'=>'width:200px;'));
         echo $this->Form->end('Sign in');
         ?>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: A related question was recently posed that may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990023/authentication-not-works-when-users-are-stored-in-alternative-table/23012630#23012630

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple user register/login application I suggest that you take a look at the [CakeDC Users Plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/users).

Answer (score 0):

First Use AuthComponents just on your AppController not on UsersController. So, your code-

## In AppController.php

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
 class AppController extends Controller 
 {
 public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
 public $components = array('Session',
                        'Auth' => array(
                           'authenticate' => array(
                                'Form' => array (
                                    'fields' => array('username'=>'email','password'=>'password')
 ))));  


}
```

## UsersController.php

remove `public $helpers, public $components` from UsersController.php

## In login.ctp

Thus you change default `username` to `email`, so use `email` on view.

```
   <?php
         echo $this->Form->create();
         echo $this->Form->input('email',array('style'=>'width:200px;'));
         echo $this->Form->input('password',array('style'=>'width:200px;'));
         echo $this->Form->end('Sign in');
         ?>
```

Comment: It solves my problem. Thanks for it. One more thing that i want to know about Cake login is, Suppose i get login using email and password and after then i clicked back button of browser(i am using google chrome), it takes me to the login screen again. Now if i am giving any wrong password or edit the email. It gets login.I don't understand why its happening ? Is it due to the cookie that cake php made in my browser?

Comment: Well, if its solve your problem then tick this as an answer. And what you are asking about back button, I have this answer but you need to create another question because it will be a good question i think and other may get help from that question. Better not to answer here. Thank you...